# Sum the result of a query

Tags: sql-server

I have made a query with the below code which works fine. I then need to sum the diff column which will give me the total amount. It also needs to ignore the first row in the sum to reflect the true result.

```
select col,
    col - coalesce(lag(col) over (order by id), 0) as diff
from t;
```

```
+.......+.......+
|COL    |DIFF   |
+.......+.......+               
|1200   |0      |
|1200   |0      |
|1202   |2      |
|1204   |2      |
|1204   |0      |
|1208   |4      |
+.......+.......+
```

This is what the query result is, i need to have the result as the sum of the diff column which in this case would be 8.

As added by OP as comment, adding to the question.

Below is the query. How can I improve the performance.

```sql
Select SUM(result)
FROM (
    select col1,
        col1 - coalesce (lag(col1) over (order by col1, 0) as result
           from table
where CAST(t_stamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:00' and '15:00'
and DATEPART(DAY, T_Stamp) = '20'
and DATEPART(MONTH, T_Stamp) = '05'
and DATEPART(YEAR, T_Stamp) = '2020'
) sub
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results as formatted text.

Comment: You're still adding comments... [edit] the question :)

Comment: About performance - compare entire datetimes, not parts - datepart cannot use (possible) index on t_stamp column.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need this much complexity. You can simply use the RANGE with SUM aggregate function.

```sql
DECLARE @table Table (col1 int)

INSERT INTO @table values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

SELECT col1, SUM(col1) OVER(ORDER BY col1 RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS diff
FROm @table
ORDER BY col1
```

```
+------+------+
| col1 | diff |
+------+------+
|    1 |   15 |
|    2 |   14 |
|    3 |   12 |
|    4 |    9 |
|    5 |    5 |
+------+------+
```

** UPDATE: Based on OP edit, updating answer **

```
SELECT SUM(Diff) as diff_sum
FROM
(
SELECT col1, 
ISNULL(col1 - LAG(col1) OVER(ORDER BY Col1),0) AS DIFF
FROm @table
) AS T
```

**Result set**

```
+----------+
| diff_sum |
+----------+
|        8 |
+----------+
```

Comment: @DaleK, yes. I ran it and tested it.

Comment: This gives a total of all values in the column, i only want to sum the values upon change.

Comment: can you pleaes provide sample data and how sum should be calculated over diff ?

Comment: @RMcCarthy, updated my answer. For your requirement, this is good approach only.